# Sql Server Cross Tab query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table, crosstab

i have a data that contain date/time and other field like this

```
ASSIGN  ASSIGN_DATE                 OFFICER
ASSIGN-1    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000 Admin
ASSIGN-2    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000 Admin
ASSIGN-3    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000 Admin
ASSIGN-4    2013-07-17 10:40:15.000 TESTER
ASSIGN-5    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000 Admin
ASSIGN-5    2013-07-17 19:50:00.000 Admin
ASSIGN-6    2013-07-17 10:40:15.000 TESTER
ASSIGN-7    2013-07-17 10:40:15.000 TESTER
```

i tried to use sum for sum assign-1  to assign -  7 with this

```
SELECT  OFFICER,
      sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-1' then 1 else 0 end) ASS1,
      sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-2' then 1 else 0 end) ASS2,
      sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-3' then 1 else 0 end) ASS3,
      sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-4' then 1 else 0 end) ASS4,
      sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-5' then 1 else 0 end) ASS5,
      sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-6' then 1 else 0 end) ASS6,
         sum(case when [ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-7' then 1 else 0 end) ASS7


  FROM [BizView_Dev2].[dbo].[PROBLEM_ASSIGN_LOG]
  GROUP BY [ASSIGN_DATE],OFFICER
```

and it's work just sum of assign

```
OFFICER ASS1    ASS2    ASS3    ASS4    ASS5    ASS6    ASS7
Admin   1        1      1        0       1      0        0
TESTER  4        0      0        1       0      1        1
```

i want to make cross tab that use `officer` and `Assign_date` (use just time 00 - 24) by date and count how many assign they are like this

```
OFFICER ASS1    ASS2    ASS3    ASS4    ASS5    ASS6    ASS7    Total
Admin                               
00       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
01       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
02       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
03       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
04       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
05       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
06       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
07       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
08       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
09       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
10       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
11       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
12       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
13       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
14       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
15       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
16       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
17       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
18       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
19       1       1      1        0       2       0      0        5
20       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
21       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
22       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
23       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
24       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
TESTER                              
00       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
01       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
02       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
03       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
04       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
05       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
06       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
07       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
08       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
09       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
10       0       0      0        1       0       1      1        3
11       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
12       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
13       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
14       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
15       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
16       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
17       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
18       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
19       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
20       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
21       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
22       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
23       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
24       0       0      0        0       0       0      0        0
```

Comment: I would group by DATEPART(HOUR, [ASSIGN_DATE]) and include it in SELECT statement. However then you would have some gaps where there were no assignments which you would have to fill. Perhaps using a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include this

`(CASE WHEN  SUBSTRING(CONVERT (varchar(20) ,ASSIGN_DATE,14),1,2) = '01' THEN '01' END) as Hour1`

but i want them to show all 24 hours even it's not exist oh, i should create a table contain 12 months right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the most efficient solution, but it works just fine:

**Test data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ASSIGN VARCHAR(255)
    , ASSIGN_DATE DATETIME2
    , OFFICER VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO #Test
    (ASSIGN, ASSIGN_DATE, OFFICER)
VALUES
    ('ASSIGN-1', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000', 'Admin')
    , ('ASSIGN-2', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000', 'Admin')
    , ('ASSIGN-3', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000', 'Admin')
    , ('ASSIGN-4', '2013-07-17 10:40:15.000', 'TESTER')
    , ('ASSIGN-5', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000', 'Admin')
    , ('ASSIGN-5', '2013-07-17 19:50:00.000', 'Admin')
    , ('ASSIGN-6', '2013-07-17 10:40:15.000', 'TESTER')
    , ('ASSIGN-7', '2013-07-17 10:40:15.000', 'TESTER');
```

**Actual query:**

```
;WITH TableName
AS (
    SELECT OFFICER
        , D.[Hour]
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS1
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS2
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS3
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS4
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS5
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS6
        , SUM(CASE WHEN T.[ASSIGN] = 'ASSIGN-7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ASS7
    FROM #Test AS T
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, [ASSIGN_DATE])) AS D([Hour])
    GROUP BY [Hour], OFFICER
)
SELECT DISTINCT T.[OFFICER]
    , D.[Hour]
    , COALESCE(ASS1, 0) AS ASS1
    , COALESCE(ASS2, 0) AS ASS2
    , COALESCE(ASS3, 0) AS ASS3
    , COALESCE(ASS4, 0) AS ASS4
    , COALESCE(ASS5, 0) AS ASS5
    , COALESCE(ASS6, 0) AS ASS6
    , COALESCE(ASS7, 0) AS ASS7
    , COALESCE(ASS1, 0) + COALESCE(ASS2, 0) + COALESCE(ASS3, 0) + COALESCE(ASS4, 0) + COALESCE(ASS5, 0) + COALESCE(ASS6, 0) + COALESCE(ASS7, 0) AS Total
FROM #Test AS T
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)) AS D([Hour])
LEFT JOIN TableName AS TN
    ON TN.[OFFICER] = T.[OFFICER]
    AND TN.[Hour] = D.[Hour]
ORDER BY T.[OFFICER]
    , D.[Hour];
```